# MultipleSearch Open Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I was wondering if there is an event for when the multipleSearch dialog is opened. I have tried looking but cant seem to find anythign to help. I have tried the following code as a test but to no evail.

```
{closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true,onOpen:function(){
        console.log("open");
    }}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, if at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to use `afterShowSearch`, `afterRedraw` or `afterChange` callback instead of `onOpen`. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching#options).